# How to migrate list template from 2010 to 2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, template

I have a task list with content that i wish to migrate to SP 2013. I have tried to save the list as a template, convert the stp file to cab and change productversion to 5 in manifest.xml but with no success.

Is there any way of doing this without purchasing any separate tools?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to take a backup of the 2010 content database and attach it to a 2013 instance to upgrade the content. You should then be able to create a 2013 List Template which will be compatible. A bit tedious I realise, but it will work, whereas mucking about with the xml will be questionable at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template from a list in Sharepoint 2013, and compare the xml from both lists.
That way you can see the differences and make the changes to convert your 2010 template to 2013

Comment: I tried this, but only the first part of the xml (the header or metadata) is possible to compare. Through the remaining xml it's very hard to find any values that can be understood and changed.