# Change list template from 2010 version to 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-list, list-template, farm-solution

Similar to: [How to migrate list template from 2010 to 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72033/how-to-migrate-list-template-from-2010-to-2013)

I've old farm solution with list schema & list instance. After deployment, list has old 2010 look, and is rendered on server side:

[image: old look]

Which magic "value" should be changed to achieve default 2013 look? This one:

[image: new look]

I tried to use diff tool and check differences between old schema and new one, however without any success. They are almost the same. BaseType for both lists is set to "0" - Generic List.

Comment: did you try this one http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Both lists are on SharePoint 2013. Are you sure that this one will work? SystemData.XML Version is 15.0.0 for list with old look.

Comment: but if you still have 2010 stuff with you then yes, i tried in my farm and its worked

Comment: I have found error, pretty stupid to be honest...

Answer (score 2):

Try this to force SP that new look.

On that list click:

1. Gear > Edit page
2. Edit web part
3. Under Appearance > Chrome Type change from *Default* to *None*
4. Click OK
5. Again Edit web part
6. Under Appearance > Chrome Type change from *None* to *Default*
7. Click OK
8. Stop editing/Save page

Now you have new 2013 look.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Forcing different "View style" than "default" in list view, results in old, 2010 look.
For example: `<ViewStyle ID="17" />` changes view to "Shaded" style.